# How to create a variable only if user input needs it?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#list of variables created
#variable1="$(command1)"
#variable2="$(command2)"
#variable3="$(command3)"
#variable4="$(command4)"
#variable5="$(command5)"

echo "some question"
read -p "Enter Input from 1 to 10" input
case $input in
   1)
    echo $variable1
    echo $variable2
    echo $variable3;;
   2)
    echo $variable2
    echo $variable3
    echo $variable4;;
   3)
    echo $variable3
    echo $variable4
    echo $variable5;;
esac
```

As you can see ,  there are some list of variables which are being created and later used in case statement based on the user input

Since all the variables aren't needed for a single user input , I think its unnecessarily increasing script runtime by creating every variable beforehand .I dont want all variables to get created beforehand .They should get created if they are required by the selected user input

I know i can directly create those variables inside the possible user inputs in case statement so that specific variable gets created only if that input is selected by user ,but there are many inputs and each input needs multiple variables and it will really make script quite long .
I was wondering if there is a smart way to achieve this which will help reduce script runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a pattern-action pair is terminated with `;;&`, bash continues with the next pattern as if the current one didn't match, instead of returning from the `case` command currently being processed.

Utilizing this feature the example script in your question can be simplified to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -r -p 'prompt' input
case $input in
(1)
  command1 ;;&
(1|2)
  command2 ;;&
(1|2|3)
  command3 ;;&
(2|3)
  command4 ;;&
(3)
  command5 ;;
esac
```